# compare 2 files, delete uncommon strings scripting

Tags: linux, unix, search, scripting, awk

I have two files. 1 file has selected the input and parameters

the other has all the parameters and definitions

example file1.txt

```
 message id: "close"
 message id: "open"
 message id: "down"
 message id: "up"
```

example file2.txt

```
  #comment
  message id: "close"
  message value: " to turn off"

  #comment
  message id: "open"
  message value: "to inite"
```

etc.

I want to use file 1's string parameters to search for the message id in file2.txt.

I want to mark each message id, value and the comment with " in front of it so it looks like this: (ONLY if the message id is in file1)

```
 " #comment
 " message id: "close"
 " message value: " to turn off"

 " #comment
 " message id: "open"
 " message value: "to inite"
```

Can anyone tell me where to start??

Comment: Probably a job for your `awk` or `python` script.

Comment: what's the difference between file3.txt and file2.txt after the deletion

Comment: file2 would have the original.. file 3 would only contain the message ids that are in file1

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ cat file1.txt | xargs -I % grep file2.txt -e % | cut -d \" -f 2
open
close
```

**Edit:** Another way.

```
$ for i in `cat file1.txt`; do grep file2.txt -e $i | cut -d \" -f 2; done
open
close
```

Comment: but that means i would need to input "message id: "close"" each time?

Comment: It writes to file on its own, so you don't have to edit the file yourself.

Comment: hnm. for some reason, it's giving me this error, "xargs: Missing closing quote (' or ") before newline"

Comment: Did you copy it exactly? Works fine for me.

Comment: mayb because im using msk took kit for windows?? .. i copied and pasted, just using different filenames.

Comment: "cat get_ids_only.txt | xargs grep -s default.po -e | sed 's/default.po://' > file3.txt"

Comment: actually, im using my mac's terminal and it still says something about unterminated quote after xargs.

Comment: `grep -A 1 -B 1 -f file1.txt file2.txt` will print the matched line along with +/- 1 line

but if you just want to modify the file2 then better use awk or python as Basile suggested

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a comment above the records in file 2 and they are separated by empty lines that contain no whitespace, you could try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$0]; next}$2 in A{gsub(/^|\n/,"&\"")}1' file1 RS= ORS='\n\n' FS='\n' file2
```

With your particular sample files there is white space in character position 1 and or 2 that needs to be matched, for example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[" " $0]; next}$2 in A{gsub(/^|\n/,"&\"")}1' file1 RS= ORS='\n\n' FS='\n' file2
```